# find any script which is running for more than say 30 minutes in Linux System

Tags: linux, cron, grep, find, ps

Please share command to find any script which is running for more than say 30 minutes. in Linux System

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  Just so you know, you might consider asking this question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.  Further, this might give you some pointers: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-get-process-start-date-and-time.html

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134/how-do-you-find-the-age-of-a-long-running-linux-process

Answer (score 1):

the `ps` command has an `etimes` field, that gives you the time since a given process has been started, in seconds.

the following bash script will output the PIDs of processes that have been running for longer than 30 minutes.

```
#!/bin/sh
MIN=30
SEC=$((MIN*60))
ps -eo etimes=,pid= | while read sec pid; do
 if [ ${sec} -gt ${SEC} ]; then
   echo ${pid}
 fi
done
```

Comment: hi @umlaute, your script gives on my box (standard Ubunut 12.04 setup) a "ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes"". What do I do wrong?

Comment: ah yes; it seems that only newer versions (>=3.3.0) of procps (actually procps-ng)  have the "etimes" field. i'm using debian/wheezy that ships with procps-3.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU date + ps, this gives you a list of pids older than 30 minutes:

```
# weird format to match ps -o lstart
cutoff=$(date -d '30 minutes ago' +'%a %b %e %T %Y')
ps -e -o lstart,pid |
awk '$0 < "'"$cutoff"'" {print NF}'
```

On linux, you can then check whether /proc/$pid/exe resolves to a known interpreter like /bin/sh, /bin/bash or /usr/bin/python - if so, you know it's a script.